# Growth of powers of symmetric subsets in a finite group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, additive-combinatorics

(This question was originally asked [on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4779895), where it was answered in the abelian case)

Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $A$ be a symmetric subset of $G$ containing the identity (i.e., $A^{-1}=A$ and $1\in A$). Then the powers of $A$ will form a chain $A\subsetneq A^2\subsetneq A^3\subsetneq\cdots\subsetneq A^d=\langle A\rangle$.

It turns out that if $A$ is a large subset of $G$, then $d$ must be small. One strategy for proving this sort of result is to show that if $d$ is large, then you can find many disjoint translates of $A$ inside $G$, forcing $A$ to be a small subset of $G$.

For example, the following lemma is a slight modification of Lemma 2.1 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.0848.pdf) of Eberhard.

**Lemma.** If $(r+1)\lvert A\rvert>\lvert G\rvert$, then $d\leq3r-1$.

*Proof.* If $d\geq3r$, then we can find $g_i\in A^{3i}\setminus A^{3i-1}$ for $i=1,\ldots,r$. Then $g_iA\subseteq A^{3i+1}\setminus A^{3i-2}$, so $A,g_1A,\ldots,g_rA$ are disjoint translates of $A$ inside $G$, so $(r+1)\lvert A\rvert\leq\lvert G\rvert$. $\square$

But this lemma is not optimal. For example, the proof finds two disjoint translates of $A$ inside $A^4$, but it is actually possible to find two disjoint translates of $A$ inside $A^3$. This gives a bound of $3r-2$.

**Lemma.** If $r\geq2$ and $(r+1)\lvert A\rvert>\lvert G\rvert$, then $d\leq3r-2$.

*Proof.* If $d\geq3r-1$, then we can find $g_i\in A^{3i-1}\setminus A^{3i-2}$ for $i=2,\ldots,r$. Then $g_iA\subseteq A^{3i}\setminus A^{3i-3}$. Since $d>2$, we can find $g_0\in A$ such that $g_0A^2\neq A^2$. Pick $g_1\in A^2\setminus g_0A^2$. Then $g_0A$ and $g_1A$ are disjoint translates of $A$ inside $A^3$. Then $g_0A,g_1A,g_2A,\ldots,g_rA$ are disjoint translates of $A$ inside $G$, so $(r+1)\lvert A\rvert\leq\lvert G\rvert$. $\square$

> If $(r+1)\lvert A\rvert>\lvert G\rvert$, what is the optimal upper bound on $d$ in terms of $r$? Is it $d\leq\lfloor3r/2\rfloor+1$?

The subset $A=\{-1,0,1\}\subseteq\mathbb{Z}/(3r+2)\mathbb{Z}$ shows that $d=\lfloor(3r+2)/2\rfloor=\lfloor3r/2\rfloor+1$ is possible.

For abelian groups, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4782939) proves that $d\leq\lfloor3r/2\rfloor+1$ holds, and is therefore the optimal upper bound.

Comment: $A^i$ is usually call "ball", and the smallest $d$ such that $A^d=G$ is called diameter (of $G$ with respect to $S$). This terminology is natural since these are balls and the diameter in the Cayley graph of $G$ w.r.t. $A$. There is literature on this, showing that typically one gets smaller $d$ under assumptions such as: "$G$ is simple non-abelian", i.e. one gets bounds that would fail with abelian groups.

Comment: Thanks for this terminology. Yes, in general I would expect nonabelian groups to have smaller diameter, which is why it seems plausible that the abelian bound $d\leq\lfloor3r/2\rfloor+1$ might also hold in the nonabelian case.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure about $d\le\lfloor 3r/2\rfloor+1$, but the estimate $d\le 2r+1$ (where $r=\lfloor |G|/|A|\rfloor$ and $d$ is the smallest integer with $A^d=G$) is an immediate corollary of a result of Olson ("[On the Sum of Two Sets in a Group](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-314X(84)90047-7)", Theorem 6) saying that for any finite subset $A\subseteq G$, and any integer $n\ge 2$, one has $|A^{n}|\ge|A^{n-1}|+\frac12|A|$, unless $|A^{n}|=|A^{n+1}|$. As a result of this estimate, we have $|G|>|A^{d-1}|\ge\frac{d}2\,|A|$ whence $|G|/|A|>d/2$ and therefore $d\le 2r+1$, as claimed.

Notice that this argument does not assume that $1\in A$ or that $A^{-1}=A$.

It should be possible to improve the coefficient further, at least under some extra restrictions, using various nonabelian extensions of Kneser's theorem, such as a result of Zemor ("[A generalization to noncommutative groups of a theorem of Mann](https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(94)90279-8)", Theorem 2).

For abelian groups much more can be said; for instance, Theorem 2.13 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.2908) classifies all finite subsets $A\subseteq G$ with $0\in A=-A$ such that $d>(4/3)r$.

#### Added December 15, 2023.

Your guess is, essentially correct, as shown by Hamidoune over 40 years ago. Namely, Theorem 7.4 from [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S019566988180042X) gives the estimate $$ d\le\left\lfloor\frac{|G|-2|A|}{2\lfloor(|A|+2)/3\rfloor}\right\rfloor + 2. $$ The right-hand side is easily verified to be $\frac{3|G|}{2(|A|-1)}-1$ at most.

Comment: Here is a self-contained argument getting roughly the same bound and related to OP's argument. Suppose $A^n \ne A^{n-1}$. Then there is some $g_0 \in A$ such that $g_0 A^{n-1} \ne A^{n-1}$. Let $g_1 \in A^{n-1} \setminus g_0 A^{n-1}$. Then $g_1A$ and $g_0A^{n-2}$ are disjoint subsets of $A^n$, so $|A^n| \ge |A| + |A^{n-2}|$.

Comment: @SeanEberhard: very nice!

Comment: @SeanEberhard Maybe the latter bound can be improved using that $(A^{n-1}\setminus g_0A^{n-1})A$ and $g_0A^{n-2}$ are disjoint subsets of $A^n$.